# Ubuntu, NodeJs and environment file

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, environment-variables, dotenv

I have an issue with my NodeJS myApp1 and loading of its .ENV file (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

When I execute it like below - it loads partially my params inside my .ENV file

```
root@Monster:/# node /home/Octopus/Applications/Test/MyApp1/1.0.12/server.js
```

If I then do this

```
cd Home
cd tb (my username)
```

and then run the exact same command again --> all .ENV values would just be undefined / don't get loaded.

Question: How can the dir and path I execute my NodeJS app from in Ubuntu - affect how/if my .ENV params get loaded (partially) or not?

An example of a line in my .env file: `PROJECT_NAME=Test`

It is loaded like this in NodeJS (as the first command):`require('dotenv').config();`

It it used in like this: `process.env.PROJECT_NAME`.

The .env file is located in the root of my project's folder - again everything works on windows and in another project on Ubuntu as well...But this project doesn't load correctly for whatever weird reason?

**Almost solved!**

This fails:

```
root@Monster:/# pm2 start /home/Octopus/Applications/Test/MyApp/1.0.17/server.js --name MyApp
```

This works:

```
root@Monster:/# cd home/Octopus/Applications/Test/MyApp/1.0.17/
root@Monster:/home/Octopus/Applications/Test/MyApp/1.0.17# pm2 start server.js --name MyApp
```

But why is there a difference?

Comment: Can you provide the `.env` file and the path of that file ?

Comment: Can you show us your `server.js` and `.env` ?

Comment: I have updated the description - with answers to your questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

This method always works on Ubuntu:

```
root@Monster:/# cd home/Octopus/Applications/Test/MyApp/1.0.17/
root@Monster:/home/Octopus/Applications/Test/MyApp/1.0.17# pm2 start server.js --name MyApp
```

to first cd into the deployment-dir and then run PM2 from there.